# ¿Cómo enviar el valor del botón por medio de Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Tengo este formulario que envío sin recargar, el asunto es que cuando utilizo el `if(isset($_POST['send2'])){}` no reconoce el botón `send2`.

Aquí mi código:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.para_guardar').submit(function(){

    var x = confirm("¿Estás seguro que quieres guardar?");
      if (x){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "add2.php",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
                //$('#result').show(3000);

                $('#result').html(data).
            fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();

            }
        });//end ajax
        return false;
      }

    });
});
//

//Este script es para limpiar los text box despues del submit.
function limpiar() {
    setTimeout('document.cliente.reset()',2000);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<div id="cliente" class="tabcontent">
  <div id="camn">
      <form  method="post" name="cliente"  class="para_guardar"   onSubmit="return limpiar()" id="cliente"  autocomplete="off">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <table width="358" height="270" border="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Codigo del cliente:</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="cod_cli"></label>
      <input type="text" name="cod_cli" id="cod_cli" required/></td>
      <td><div id="result"  ></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nombre del cliente:</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="nom_cli"></label>
      <input type="text" name="nom_cli" id="nom_cli" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Telefono:</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="tel"></label>
      <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fax:</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="fax"></label>
      <input type="text" name="fax" id="fax" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-Mail</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label for="correo"></label>
      <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo" required/></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="send2" id="send2"  value="Guardar" />
</p>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>

  </center>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['send2'])){
   $cod_cli = $_POST['cod_cli'];
   $nom_cli = $_POST['nom_cli'];
   $tel = $_POST['tel'];
   $fax = $_POST['fax'];
   $correo = $_POST['correo'];

   $link2 = mysql_connect("localhost","root","master3.1416");
   mysql_select_db("roda",$link2);

   mysql_query("INSERT INTO cliente (cod_cli, nom_cli, tel, fax, correo)
                            VALUES ('$cod_cli' , '$nom_cli', '$tel', '$fax',  '$correo' )",$link2);

   $my_error = mysql_error($link2);
   echo"<br>";

   echo "<span>Registro guardado</span>";
 }
```

El asunto como dije arriba, es que me reconozca el valor del `submit`, ósea no reconoce el botón `send2`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes conseguir con el método [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

> El método `.serializeArray()` crea una matriz de objetos,
>   lista para ser codificada como una cadena `JSON`.

En pocas palabras [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) no incluye los botones (`buttons`)

Hay dos maneras de solucionarlo:

**Ejemplo #1 con `.serializeArray()`:** ([`código original`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4007951/2097224))

```js
$('#send2').on('click', function(e) {
    
   e.preventDefault();
   var formData = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
   formData.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value });
    
   console.log( formData );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="cliente" class="tabcontent">
<div id="camn">
<form  name="cliente" class="para_guardar" id="cliente"  autocomplete="off">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="358" height="270" border="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Codigo del cliente:</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label for="cod_cli"></label>
<input type="text" name="cod_cli" id="cod_cli" required></td>
<td><div id="result"  ></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nombre del cliente:</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label for="nom_cli"></label>
<input type="text" name="nom_cli" id="nom_cli" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Telefono:</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label for="tel"></label>
<input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Fax:</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label for="fax"></label>
<input type="text" name="fax" id="fax" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>E-Mail</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label for="correo"></label>
<input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" required></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="send2" id="send2"  value="Guardar" />
</p>
</form>
</div>

</div>
```

**Ejemplo #2 con `.serialize()`:** ([`código original`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866762/2097224))

```js
$("#send2").on('click', function(e) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = $(e.target);                 
    var result = button.parents('form').serialize()
        + '&' 
        + encodeURI(button.attr('name'))
        + '='
        + encodeURI(button.attr('value'));

    console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="cliente" class="tabcontent">
<div id="camn">
<form  name="cliente"  class="para_guardar"  id="cliente"  autocomplete="off">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="358" height="270" border="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Codigo del cliente:</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label for="cod_cli"></label>
<input type="text" name="cod_cli" id="cod_cli" required/></td>
<td><div id="result"  ></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nombre del cliente:</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label for="nom_cli"></label>
<input type="text" name="nom_cli" id="nom_cli" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Telefono:</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label for="tel"></label>
<input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Fax:</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label for="fax"></label>
<input type="text" name="fax" id="fax" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>E-Mail</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label for="correo"></label>
<input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" required/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="send2" id="send2"  value="Guardar" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pero la clase que tienes en el Js ".para_guardar", a qué está haciendo referencia?
Puedes intentar con:

```
$("#send2").on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();           
    //Aquí lo que necesites hacer al momento de presionar el botón..    
});
```

O la otra que se me ocurre, es reemplazar el input "send2", por un elemento botón, ejm:

```
<button id="send2" type="submit">Registrar</button>
```